# Pass ArrayList<Object> between Fragments in NavigationComponents

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

I am writing my UI app to use Navigation architecture components, so I need to pass an ArrayList Object that implements Parcelable, but I couldn't find any information about it.

I would appreciate if you would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can not share data by safe args for now as the library does not support it. But, you can use traditional methods like this:

if you want to send ArrayList data from `FragmentA` to  `FragmentB`:

In `FragmentA`:

```
val myParcelizedObjectArrayList = ArrayList<MyParcelisedObject>()
val bundle = bundleOf("SOME_BUNDLE_KEY" to myParcelizedObjectArrayList)

findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB, bundle)
```

In `FragmentB` 's onCreate() you can get the list in this way:

```
val myArrayList = arguments?.getParcelableArrayList<MyParcelisedObject>("SOME_BUNDLE_KEY")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Steps**

**1.** You can choose to type custom serializable

[image: First Step]

**2.** then you need to look for the ArrayList

[image: second step]

**3.** you will get a window like this

[image: third step]

**4.** Lastly, in another fragment, you need to make it back to your `ArrayList` with the Object `navArgs.arrayList as ArrayList<YourObject>` and you can pass the Array list to another fragment via navigate component because `Array` objects implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface

Answer (score -1):

In your fragment class add this. Put List of Parcelable like this

```
companion object {
fun getInstance(objList : List<Parcelable>): CustomFragment {
    val args = Bundle()
    args.putParcelableArrayList("list", objList);
    val fragment = CustomFragment()
    fragment.arguments = args
    return fragment
}
}
```

Read Arguments like this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

val args = arguments
var myList : List<Parcelable> = args.getParcelableArrayList<Parcelable>("list")
}
```

Comment: This is not navigation components. You are just passing to simple fragment. I need navigation components way.